# Wrong array shape in multiclass classification using Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a data set made up of one input (an integer) and one output, to become a label, *e.g.*:

```
3042,0
3338,1
1162,3
1605,2
...
```

So the last column should become a one-hot encoding for labeling (using Keras' to_categorical()), *e.g.*:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

My input and output shapes are

```
X_data.shape: (2407060,)
y_data.shape: (2407060, 4)
```

However, I'm getting an error that my output should have shape (1,) instead of (4,), even though my final layer has 4 outputs.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                32
_________________________________________________________________
                                ...
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 68
=================================================================
Total params: 63,156
Trainable params: 63,156
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

Here's the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='nadam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

X_data = np.loadtxt(data_file, delimiter=',', usecols=(3))
y_data = to_categorical(np.loadtxt(data_file, delimiter=',', usecols=(7)))

model.fit(X_data, y_data, epochs=20, validation_split=0.3, verbose=1, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

What is going on?

Comment: What's the activation function for the last layer?

Comment: Please show the code, otherwise it's close to impossible to pin-point the error more than guessing :).

Comment: Sorry, edited with my code.

Comment: Have you tried changing the last layer activation function to categorical_crossentropy? Similar issue can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617857/keras-dense-layer-shape-error

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen well, that worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the loss function to categorical_crossentropy if the output is in one-hot format.

> [1,0,0]
>   [0,1,0]
>   [0,0,1]

If the target is an integer, you can use  sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

> 1, 2, 3