# Tensorflow Dense label shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to using Tensorflow and Python, I've seen all tutorial in the website and now I'm working with my first real dataset.

What I want to do with the NN is to predict some power plant energy consumes knowing the daily trends. I have an .xlsx file with all those (real) values. Using Pandas I'splitted and normalized the data in train set and validation set (i.e. train_x and train_y, where train_x is the time and train_y is the label). The x and y array are both numpy.ndarray and formatted as below (just the head):

```
print(train_x)
[ 644]
[ 645]
[ 646]
```

`print(train_y)
 [-0.09154356  1.10702972  1.13661838]
 [ 0.05104414  1.39112378  1.5319337 ]
 [-0.05719421  1.40702419  1.48187637]`

Then I created the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= (train_x.shape([0]))),     
keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)]) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_cross_entropy',
                optimizer='Adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

But when I run the script I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I guess the problem is about the input shape of the layer or maybe of the loss function as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617857/keras-dense-layer-shape-error), so I tried to modify the loss function in:

```
LOSS = tf.nn.categorical_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=3, labels=3)
```

and, of course, the model.compile:

```
model.compile(loss=LOSS,
                optimizer='Adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but I got the same error again:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it should be `array.shape[0]`,not `array.shape([0])`. `shape` is an attribute of a numpy array, not a method. The correct syntax should be:

```
keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= (train_x.shape[-1],)),
```

Also, change `train_x` and `train_y` to 2d arrays, with the shape of [length_of_array,1].