# Keras: wrong shape in Dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to prepare a model that takes an input image of shape 56x56 pixels and 3 channels: (56, 56, 3). Output should be an array of 216 numbers. I reuse a code from a digit recognizer and modified it a little bit:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (56,56,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(216, activation = "linear"))

from tensorflow.python.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
model.compile(loss = categorical_crossentropy,
                     optimizer = "adam",
                     metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

This is giving me an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (216,) but got array with shape (72,)
```

I know how to code aclassifier model but not to obtain an array as output, so probably I'm not setting the right shape in last Dense layer. I don't know if it should be 1 or 216.

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617857/keras-dense-layer-shape-error) that the problem could be the loss function, but I'm not sure what other loss function should I use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is saying that the target was expected to have shape (216,), but your target labels have shape (72,).  You have to fix that inconsistency.

Comment: And that 72 comes from conv2d kernel shapes?

Comment: No, it is the shape of your data, of the Y array that you gave keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see that your given   input are`input_shape = (56,56,3)`.

right now you current data shape is **56**.

After applying filter of **32** your data shape is **72**.

and this line of code your dense layer has the 256 node which means( your dense is made to receive **256** input from array but got the **72**)

`model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))`

You can either change your filter shape or change the **256** to **72**.

I hope that will work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The final layer should have the same shape as your target classes

Change

```
model.add(Dense(216, activation = "linear"))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(72, activation = "linear"))
```